# Meaning of プレミアついて２０万

Tags: meaning, words, numbers

Context: two high school girls talk about an expensive ring.

> Girl A:　 花江！そのリングどうしたの？それ　今　全然手に入らなくてネットで**プレミアついて２０万**くらいするんだよ。
>
> 花江:　 知り合いから転売してもらったんだよね。30万で。

I found on dictionaries that プレミアついて means `at a premium`, `at a higher price`. What I don't understand is: 20万 is the final price or the amount to add to the original price? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse it as:

> それ、...［プレミア（が）ついて］２０万くらいするんだよ。

"*lit.* It... [with a premium added,] costs around 200,000 yen."
→ "It... costs about 200,000 yen [at a premium]."

So 20万 is the final price.